# TeamCity, TFS, and Labeling

Tags: tfs, teamcity

We are using TeamCity for continuous integration and TFS as our VCS.  I am able to apply a label to a build using the VCS Labeling build feature.  This works exactly as we expect it to but with one minor glitch that we can’t seem to figure out.

In the TFS source control explorer, I go to the top level of the project.  From there I can select view history.  On the view history I select the Labels tab.  Here I see something like this.

```
Name    | User   | Date   |Changeset | Comment
MyLabel |username|datetime|12345     |TeamCity automatic label
```

This is all well and good except that the Changeset number is always the very first one that was ever done for this branch.  Is there a way to configure the changeset setting?  As a bonus, setting the comment would also be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a glitch, but rather how TFS labels works.
The change set shown on the label is the change set of when the root folder within the label was last modified.
The reason for this is because labels are not a point in time snapshot of files as they are mutable.

Comment: Microsoft calls labeling a snapshot. "By using labels, you can take a snapshot of your files so that you can refer back to that snapshot later."  I appreciate the explination but it doesn't really solve my problem.  There must be a way to do this.

Comment: That definition does stand. A label is a collection of files at a specific version, where the versions are tracked per file rather then the entire group of file. This allows you to update a file to a new version inside a label. Effectively, a label is almost like a new branch. I looked into this a few years ago and came to a dead end, and I haven't heard of this changing since. Instead of relying on the changeset column of the label, I put the actual changeset number in the label name. Not ideal, but a potential solution to your problem.